# How to prevent from drawing overlapping axis ticks when adding a line to scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(X[1],y)
y_projection = X.dot(theta_after)
ax.plot(X[1], y_projection)
plt.show()
```

Above is my code. What I'm trying to do is basically fitting a line to the data. I use gradient descent method to find the suitable theta.

The problem I came across is that the code above created two x-axis and y-axis and that they were overlapping on each other

[This is the result generated from the above code. I'm not allowed to embed a pic now, please click on this to open the pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ8K4.png)

X - is a 97*2 matrix in which the first column is all 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an extra Axes with your second line. Just remove the following line:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

You already have an Axes when you run `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`